# Laravel get queries from url

Tags: php, laravel, url

How do I get all query parameters from the url?

So let's say the url is:

http://website.com?page=1&?forum=test

I need this part in my controller:

http://website.com**?page=1&?forum=test**

the query parameters can be different with every request. So `Input::get('page');` or `Input::get('forum');`does not help because I 
don't know what to can expect.

Already looked at the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests) but I can't find it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get all parameters with

```
$params = $request->query->all();
```

More information about the request object can be found at the [Symfony's Request documentation](http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html) page.

This is a recommended way of accessing Request data, never rely on Superglobal arrays like `_GET` and such.