# Laravel how to get the current URL without a domain name?

Tags: laravel

How to get the view address

> questions/ask?title=Laravel%20how%20to%20get%20the%20current%20URL%20without%20a%20domain%20name

Outside the controller

Comment: To get query strings, `request()->query()->all()` [from this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43706149/3585500)

Comment: Or yours specifically, `request()->query('title')`. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#retrieving-input

Answer (score 41):

You can get current URL without a domain name in anywhere by:

```
request()->path()
```

Comment: Thank you Thank you Thank you

Comment: Merci Beaucoup, Merci Beaucoup, Merci Beaucoup

Comment: `\Request::path()` in case someone wants to use the facade.

Comment: This information is so hard to find on the internet!

Comment: `path()` FYI does not return query params.